# Writing different languages text to CSV ERROR

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Using Python 3.5 to grab some information from different sites, then dump it to pickle, and then i need to create csv file from some information.

Information is a list with some arguments numeric and text.
Text information could be on different languages, and this text i must write to csv file. But when i write it to the csv, i ve got an Error like

"UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0141' in position 0: character maps to "

```
import pickle
import csv
with open('poland_russia_data.pickle','rb') as f:
    data_new=pickle.load(f, encoding="ascii")
print(data_new[0])
>>>Łyk idealnego orzeźwienia może wywołac uśmiech na Twojej twarzy!
print(data_new[1])
>>>Некоторый текст
with open('somefile.csv','w',newline='')  as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(data_new[0])
    writer.writerow(data_new[1])
```

How can i write it correctly to file?

Comment: Why have you chosen ascii encoding?

Comment: And which encodeing i should use? a i understand, system encoding is 'cp1251'. If i use `code data_new=pickle.load(f, encoding="cp1251") ` and then `code with open('somefile.csv','w',newline='',encoding="cp1251") ` ive got an error.

Comment: Which encoding includes the characters you want - utf-8 is normal see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: if i use utf-8 instead of 'Łyk idealnego orzeźwienia może wywołac uśmiech na Twojej twarzy!' i have got in csv file 'ЕЃyk idealnego orzeЕєwienia moЕјe wywoЕ‚ac uЕ›miech na Twojej twarzy! ' that is not correct

Comment: What encoding does the app you are reading the file in use?

Comment: This is json data from twitter and FB.

Comment: JSON is always utf8 - but the question I asked is what does the app that reads the csv file use as its encoding to read the file

Comment: @Mark, as i said, CSV i should open with MS Excel, and it used 'win-1251'